# File Explorer (File Selection) android

Tags: android

I want to let the user select some files from his android device to upload it on server. 
how can i show a file explorer and let the user pick any(image/audio/vedio) file (single or multiple selection) to upload it.
how can  i implement this.

Please help.
thanks..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this tutorial:

http://android-er.blogspot.com/2010/01/implement-simple-file-explorer-in.html

and extend it after your needs.

Comment: thanks ..but that doesn't solve the problem ...how can i select the files .

Comment: extend the list view with a check box or whatever you consider appropriate

Comment: can you help me on this with a snippet or something..?

Comment: see: http://appfulcrum.com/2010/09/12/listview-example-3-simple-multiple-selection-checkboxes/

Answer (score 1):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);  
intent.setType("audio/*");  
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select music"));
```

Comment: this will only select the Audio files.